# Word for a Single-Word Request

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word for when you request a single word for some phrase or thought?

Example sentence:

> By golly, it's time to make a ____ on EL&U!

Things I've tried:

- I've searched this site for "single-word request" but I couldn't seem to find anything of interest.
- SWR is an abbreviation, and other people wouldn't know what it stood for.
- Singlewordrequest isn't proper English, I believe.

Comment: No, there isn't, afaik. I had assumed that's why we call them "single-word-requests" here. On the other hand, if we made up a special word for them, maybe there'd be fewer of them.

Comment: "A" and "single' are modifiers for the item you want which is "word."

Comment: @Stan: Very clever. But "word" doesn't include the notion of "request".

Comment: @JohnLawler: Perhaps we should, then. Or split off a special site for single-word requests.

Comment: I believe such a device is called a reverse dictionary. The result is a word for a given phrase. A Thesaurus is another device for obtaining a different word for another given one. What are we missing?

Comment: a good meta question. ps: ck sp of' thinks'

Comment: "request" is a given when we pick up a reference to find an answer to curiosity.

Comment: Even Fowler couldn't find *le mot juste* https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mot%20juste and fell back on 'technical terms' to cover everything: spondees, personification, aposiopesis.

Comment: 'Word-search' might be suitable.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Oops! Added.

Comment: If we were to use 'plain language' rather than domain-specific jargon,  "It's time to ~ask for the right word to use~ at that English word site."  not "make a jargon-something"

Comment: 'make a request for a type of question" is pretty convoluted.   People "ask a question" ... and don't particularly enjoy categorizing their type of question as that is a sort of "word-game poll tax"  to choose the right tag to get in the door ? ; )

Comment: Are you mad? My apologies if you actually are.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I don't think that's proper English, but by all means post it as an answer. // I just feel that any idea should have a word.

Comment: Cerberus, if you feel that every idea should have a single word, then get ready to do a whole lot of coining.  Or switch to German.

Comment: @aparente001: Oh, surely not! I'll just ask about every idea on this site, problem solved.

Comment: Why isn't monoword the singular of multiword? A monosyllable word exists as the singular of a non-existent multisyllable one, after all.

Comment: @Stan same reason there isn't monomedia and monovitamin, because reasons...

Comment: You know it's called an SWR, silly you. Has been for years. Very much officially so. Not enough for your tastes, eh. That earns you a hammer-wielding Norse god of hallowing, fertility, and oak trees :‑Þ.

Comment: @RegDwigнt♦: But that's not a word! We SWRers are a picky lot. I'll gladly be hallowed. Hope it doesn't burn.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's frivolous.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest we call such a thing a

> **monologos** *n*
>   A single word request that involves the feeling you get when you can't really think of something interesting to ask but you still want to waste people's time anyway.

Comment: C'est pas mal! And it isn't even impossible Greek.

Comment: Although it does sound more like a single word without a request...(can't ever make an SWRer happy).

Comment: And isn't that an improvement?

Comment: Yes, but, as the OP, I could not possibly acknowledge that. I always want something else, something more.

Comment: Sorry, when you come here to ask your question you can only get more of the same.

Comment: I'll change my question to be about something else entirely.

Comment: My answer will probably still fit.

Comment: Good effort, but _single female lawyer_ is mo bettah.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [open-form compound word](http://blog.sfbar.org/2013/07/31/legal-writing-tip-the-three-types-of-compound-words/) *clothes shopping*:

> Realistically, before embarking on this journey I thought that quitting clothes shopping might help me clear a few bucks from my credit card.
>   [- The Sydney Morning Herald](https://www.google.com.au/amp/s/amp.smh.com.au/lifestyle/life-and-relationships/i-quit-clothes-shopping-for-a-year-and-this-is-what-i-learnt-20161229-gtjcx2.html)

As English is a productive language, consider the variant ‘**word shopping**’ to be a ‘single’ (open compound) word synonym to *single-word-request*.

The parallel to clothes shopping includes

- having a good idea of the context (person / sentence);
- not necessarily knowing what it would be beforehand; and
- knowing a good fit upon seeing it

One might extend the analogy to having someone else produce the item, or paying for it (via rep points), but these are incidental.

The sample sentence, as given, doesn’t lend itself immediately to this term, but you might say:

- It's time to *go **word shopping*** at EL&U!

Admittedly, this is a somewhat cheeky answer. If open compound words are to be considered, *single-word request* already fits the bill. :)

Comment: Cheeky, cheeky! While the meaning matches my request, as a SWRer I could not possibly use an "open compound"! For it isn't a single word, and that doesn't fit my conception of language.